# Apache proxy to another internal server?

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I proxy from WEBSERVER(192.168.1.1) to EMAILSERVER(192.168.1.2)?

Using APACHE and WEBMIN as WebServer.

Example:

http://www.myweb.com --> 192.168.1.1

I would like to proxy as (without redirecting the user URL):

http://www.myweb.com/webmail --> http://192.168.1.2/webmail

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an Reverse Proxy.
This can be done with apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html)

For further explanation look [here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)